# HbaseTestingUtility and MapReduce Job

Tags: testing, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to run a test, using HbaseTestingUtility, on very basic mapper that extends TableMapper. 
In my test class I start a MiniCluster using  `utility.startMiniCluster()` and create a test table using `utility.createTable(tablename_bytes, familyname_bytes)` in the setup method.

Then I Launch the mapper  using:

```
Job job = new Job(utility.getConfiguration()); //Job.getInstance();
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, new Scan(),MyBasicHbaseMapper.class,Text.class, Text.class, job);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

This is the error I get:

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:57276/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/cloudera/htrace/htrace-core/2.04/htrace-core-2.04.jar
```

This jar file is in `~/.m2/repository/org/cloudera/htrace/htrace-core/2.04/htrace-core-2.04.jar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, and after banging my head against it for a few hours, finally realized the solution...

Immediately after you invoke:

```
utility.startMiniCluster();
```

Invoke:

```
utility.startMiniMapReduceCluster();
```

The method #startMiniCluster only starts miniclusters of HBase, HDFS, and Zookeeper. Starting a MapReduce minicluster requires #startMiniMapReduceCluster!!

BTW, after your test processing is finished, be sure to invoke:

```
utility.shutdownMiniMapReduceCluster();
utility.shutdownMiniCluster();
```